# SimpleDateFormat mmddyyyy returns improper data for month

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want a timestamp field. I tried the below to get time in `mmddyyyyhhmmss` format.

All the fields give proper data but the month field has improper value.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mmddyyyyhhmmss");
String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
```

O/P I get is 13132013021331. What I expect is 03133013021331.

Comment: Did you look in the documentation for SimpleDateFormat to check what all those letters mean? What did it say for "mm"?

Comment: "Insanity": doing the same thing over again and expecting different results. How should java know that one `mm` is month, and the other `mm` is minutes?

Comment: Anybody ever notice that every other question that's asked 5x/day everybody dogpiles on with 'close as duplicate' votes, but this one we all dogpile on with the same old answer to see who gets the 25 rep?

Comment: @Affe yes exactly right, I to noticed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Month should be `MM` not mm

mm means Minutes

Answer (score 1):

> SimpleDateFormat mmddyyyy returns improper data for month

coz your format for month is wrong.

it should be:

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyyhhmmss");
MM---> Month
mm---> minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyyhhmmss"); 
String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
```

You used "mm" twice - once for month (incorrect) and again for minutes (correct).

Comment: The "hh" is almost certainly inappropriate too.